# Determine whether Powerpoint is in Presentation mode or not

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, powerpoint

I have written a program that pops up and plays a Sound when a interval has elapsed that the user can set by himself.

Now I want it to stay silent when Powerpoint is running in presentation mode and the interval elapses, so the program won't appear at the top of the screen and playing the sound when doing presentations with an external audience.

The used PowerPoint versions are 07/10/13 (12.0/14.0/15.0) I couldnt find any way to determine if the presentation mode is running or not.

This program is no PowerPoint addin or something like that just a normal WPF desktop application.

Comment: Powerpoint versions aren't dates. There are hundrends of sites and articles about Office development, even an entire DevCenter about office in MSDN. Check about Office Interop, specifically about Powerpoint

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know but its the name of the version (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office#Version_history), so I need to handle versions 12.0/14.0/15.0 . Im not sure about the Interop, I never used a interop isn't it a way to control something? Because i dont want to control anything, i just need to know if the presentation mode is running or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry if that looks a bit greedy to answer my own question, but i think this answer will help someone with the same problem:

Simply add the COM reference called "Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Libary" - it appears in the reference list as "Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint"

The following code tests for running Presentations and was tested working for versions 2007/10/13 (12.0/14.0/15.0):

```
var PPT = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

if (PPT.SlideShowWindows.Count > 0)
{ //a PowerPoint Presentation mode is currently running}
else 
{//there is no PowerPoint Presentation mode running}
```

### EDIT:

Some error reports have shown that just doing it the above way can cause an exception if PowerPoint is not running at all or when the presentation mode is not active, so I modified the code a little bit:

```
private bool IsPPTPresentationRunning()
{
    Process[] prozesse = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process p in prozesse)
    {//searches for a running PowerPoint process
        if (p.ProcessName == "POWERPNT")
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PPT = 
                new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
                if (PPT.SlideShowWindows.Count > 0)
                 return true; 
                else
                 return false; 
            }
            //Catches any exception that seems to get thrown when
            // powerpoint is not in Presentation mode
            catch (Exception) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help... "How to Automate control PowerPoint Slide" https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-Automate-control-23cd2a8f

Comment: Thanks for first, seems like i have to use the Interop.. But I tried to add the 3 Interop References for my 3 PPT versions but Visual Studio keeps telling me that i can only have one of them references. So is this possible at all with 3 different versions of PPT?

Comment: Use only 1 interop which supports the latest PPT version. it should have a backward support as well...

Comment: Iam trying currently but now got a new problem: The only Reference i can find for PowerPoint 15 (PPT 2013) is a COM Reference ("Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Libary") and not a .net one (the latest one there has version 14 (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint) and I can only find VBA examples for it on MSDN. The question is can i even use COM references without using VBA? sorry if this question sounds narrow minded but iam a starter..

Comment: There is no problem using a com object with .NET simply go to the toolbox and add the selected com object.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do something that works for the 15.0 version and i have send it out for testing on 12.0 and 14.0. But iam currently unsure about the compability for those three versions.. Do you know if they are backward compatible?

Comment: The testing resulted in the answer that the interop is backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if any other program (not only PowerPoint) is running full screen or not.
Here is the answer that exactly what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744720/1977363

Comment: Is fullscreen meant in the way games work fullscreen? or does it also include windowes applications which are maximised?

Answer (score 0):

Visit the below link. I think it will help

[Detect if Full Screen mode is on](http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/09/how-to-detect-if-another-application-is.html)

Comment: PowerPoint slide shows are usually but NOT always in full screen mode, so testing just for that will usually but not always work. If you get a reference to the PPT application, it's SlideShowWindows.Count property will tell you the number of presentations in slideshow view.  If >0 there's a show in progress.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg if you had post this as an answer (as far as i can tell by now, testing is not all done) it would have been the answer that i accept for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Marv No worries; you posted a code snippet that directly answers the question.  That's better.