# Detecting if a window is full screen

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, fullscreen

My English is not so good, but I try to make a logic story.

I like home domotica, so I made a program in visual basic (visual studio) that control de lightning of my room (with Arduino). A function of the program is turning on/off the lights when I run an application in full screen (for movies, gaming). I used a code for detect full screen from internet, but the part for comparing the forgroundscreen with the desktop isn't working, I get a falsely fullscreen. :

```
    Private Function detectfullscreen()
    'Detect if the current app is running in full screen
    Dim runningFullScreen As Boolean = False
    Dim appBounds As RECT
    Dim screenBounds As Rectangle
    Dim hWnd As IntPtr

    'get the dimensions of the active window
    hWnd = GetForegroundWindow()

    If hWnd <> Nothing AndAlso Not hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        'Check we haven't picked up the desktop or the shell
        If Not (hWnd.Equals(desktopHandle) OrElse hWnd.Equals(shellHandle)) Then
            'If hWnd <> GetDesktopWindow() Then
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, appBounds)
            'determine if window is fullscreen
            screenBounds = Screen.FromHandle(hWnd).Bounds
            If (appBounds.Bottom - appBounds.Top) = screenBounds.Height AndAlso (appBounds.Right - appBounds.Left) = screenBounds.Width Then
                runningFullScreen = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return runningFullScreen
End Function
```

The rest of de code (for the register) is:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Public Structure RECT
Public Left As Integer
Public Top As Integer
Public Right As Integer
Public Bottom As Integer
End Structure

   Private desktopHandle As IntPtr = GetDesktopWindow()
   Private shellHandle As IntPtr = GetShellWindow()

<DllImport("user32.dll")> Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")> Private Shared Function GetDesktopWindow() As IntPtr
End Function
```

The code works perfect and i use a timer to run this sub, but if I go to desktop, the program also thinks I use a full screen application.

My operatingsystem is Windows 10, is it possible that I need an other way to detect if the current forgroundscreen is the desktop? I try to use de ID of the desktop, but when I restart the computer, this ID will change.

I hoop my story was clear. Thank you for reading this!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check to see if another program is running full screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743956/is-there-a-way-to-check-to-see-if-another-program-is-running-full-screen)

Comment: The way it reveals the desktop is a bit hacky.  I *think* you also need to call IsWindowVisible().