# Is there any way to detect if an external process is running on exclusive fullscreen mode?

Tags: c#, directx

spent the whole day looking up for a solution, but I couldn't find it

I'm not talking about borderless windowed fullscreen, but those exclusive fullscreen mode that usually games use

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get list of the process independently from your mode using `System.Diagnostics.Process`. Than you can just find any process by name or other properties.

**UPDATED**

So I have tried some solutions, but for now found one that works if process if full-screen right now, not minimized. Pretty much that:
[Is there a way to check to see if another program is running full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743956/is-there-a-way-to-check-to-see-if-another-program-is-running-full-screen)

My code Snippet (Runs in loop and checks if the process with specific name is fullsreen)
https://pastebin.com/qwE7ZXVt

Another possible solution based on window into style flags
https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/6maqdd/detecting_if_window_in_the_foreground_is/
But I was unable to make it work. You can try to PM folks there.

Also this site was very handy
https://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I got it until this part, but how do I detect the exclusive fullscreen?

Comment: @user6516781 I misunderstood the question then, Wow, that's an interesting task, actually. Updated my answer, see if it helps.