# How to disable full screen exclusive mode?

Tags: c#, windows, directx

I have a computer with Windows 7. I have got 3D simulator installed. This simulator provides window. I want to place transparent window on top of simulator's window (with my extra drawing).

Problem is that simulator's window switches to "full screen exclusive mode" on mouse click. That makes hardware work faster. But that hides the rest of windows (even topmost) including mine transparent window.

Is the a way to disable full screen mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very interesting post (and it is related to my question):

[Detect if user has any application running in fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536373/detect-if-user-has-any-application-running-in-fullscreen)

Here is a little tip from me: if you are using Presagis Vega Prime then you can switch full screen exclusive mode on and off using acf-file (Full Screen checkbox at Pipeline\Window).

In my case I switched Full Screen off and configured Coordinates so result 3D simulator's window still covers full screen ("fake" Full Screen Mode).

After that there are no problems with my transparent window.